# Test if a user have access to an item in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a project where I have a username (but not the password) and need to check if the user can access an item. This must be on the item-level and not the web level since rights may not be inherited.

I am aware of the SPWeb.CheckPermissions but figured it will only test if the user can access the actual spweb.

Thanks

== EDIT ==

I was able to achieve this by doing this

```
var item = properties.ListItem;
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(@"domain\logonname");
item.DoesUserHavePermissions(user, SPBasePermissions.OpenItems);
```

My question remains a bit however. Is this possible to do via the web service api?

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: That doesn't help as those three have totally different web service methods. Which system do you target? :)

Comment: Currently 2010, but also the other versions!

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint 2013 you can use the REST API to query static methods. An interesting method would be the [`SPUtility.GetPrincipalsInGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getprincipalsingroup.aspx). Of course you can't ask for "has open permission", but you can ask for a specific group. To query a static method refer to: [Programming using the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx), look for the section *Specifying static methods and properties as REST service URIs*. Of course you would have to call the Web Service with an authenticated user and the group needs to be enabled to be enumerable by all users.